# AndroidStudio: лаунчер и обычное приложение, что это и как сделать?

Tags: android, android-manifest, launcher

Мне нужно изменить тип приложения на "обычное", т.е. "не лаунчер". Но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать, т.к. как я почитал в интернете, ланучер приложение - это приложение, которое может представлять домашний экран устройства и показывать список работающих на устройстве приложений. Но данное приложение при установке на телефон не становится лаунчером, это просто приложение, которое запускается с домашнего экрана...

(Такой вопрос возникает, т.к. приложение не мое, а связи с разработчиком нет) Может быть приложение и так имеет тип "обычное"? Или я что-то не так понял... 
Подскажите пожалуйста.

AndroidManifest приложения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.example.n3" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > -->
        <activity
            android:name="ru.example.n3.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за ответ. Да, про эту строчку я знаю, а вот в одной статье, где делали лаучер приложение, добавляли строки <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />, <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> и android:launchMode="singleTask". Поэтому я в недоумении, лаунчер это или нет

Comment: @pavloff, хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы про строчку:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

то это не приложение-лончер, а указание с какой активити запускать ваше **обычное** приложение. Указание системе точки входа в приложение, точнее в меню приложений системы (программе-лончере, как раз), появится иконка, при нажатии на которую будет запущена указанная активити (здесь `MainActivity`).

так же:

HOME - это назначить домашний экран (что появится при нажатии кнопки "домой")

DEFAULT - назначить обработчиком по умолчанию определенного типа (файла и тп)

[Подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/intent.php) про ключи интентов